# 7-QWERTY-distance words

Tags: mathematics, word, computer-puzzle, optimization, word-search

My previous puzzle [The QWERTY-shortest word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104152/51928) was solved nearly instantly by the effective puzzling community. I also believe it is because the main parameter of the puzzle 4.7 was not perferectly set. So I propose you the same puzzle with the parameter 7, length of word "puzzles". The following is a recall of the puzzle.

---

We define the distance between two letters as the shortest way on a QWERTY keyboard to go from a letter to another with a path.

Examples:

- Q and W are seperated by a distance of 1.
- 2 for E and T.
- 2 for I and N going through J.
- 9 for Z and P.

[image]

Can you find:

1. $S$: The shortest word in Merriam Webster such that its number of letters is greater or equal than 7
2. $L$: The longest word in Merriam Webster such that its number of letters is lesser or equal than 7

Score is $L$ minus $S$. Your aim is to get the highest score.

Example:

- Love, $L=9$
- Puzzles, $S=24$

Score is $9-24 = -15$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best score so far is

> L - S = 40

S

> [SEERESS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seeress) which scores **4**

L

> [AMALAKA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amalaka) which scores **44**